# Warning: undefined-func-template for C++17 class template deduction for std::unique_lock with clang

Tags: c++17, template-argument-deduction, class-template

test.cpp:

```
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock lk{m};
}
```

When I compile I get:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -std=c++17 -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat
test.cpp:5:22: warning: instantiation of function 'std::<deduction guide for unique_lock><std::mutex>' required here, but no definition is available
      [-Wundefined-func-template]
    std::unique_lock lk{m};
                     ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/std_mutex.h:194:16: note: forward declaration of template entity is here
      explicit unique_lock(mutex_type& __m)
               ^
test.cpp:5:22: note: add an explicit instantiation declaration to suppress this warning if 'std::<deduction guide for unique_lock><std::mutex>' is explicitly
      instantiated in another translation unit
    std::unique_lock lk{m};
                     ^
1 warning generated.
```

What is it complaining about and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a compiler bug, that's [been fixed](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dMj9MP4BmRexKAUH).